# Page specific header/margin with wicked_pdf?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I have a rails 3.2 application that I use wicked_pdf to generate PDF files (reports).

My PDFs have a edge to edge image that makes up the header for the first page but no header on the remaining pages.

I am looking for a way to either have a header only on the first page or have differing margin settings for page 2 and beyond.  Another option I would consider is if I could just have two different headers, one for the first page and one for page 2 and beyond.  Any ideas?

Relevant gem versions:

rails (3.2.2)

wicked_pdf (0.7.9)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this as 2 separate PDFs and then merge them together with pdftk.